# Building R package with Rtools4.0 on Windows 10

Tags: r-package, rtools, sbml

I am trying to build an `R` package using [RTools4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/testing/rtools40.html) on Windows 10 machine. My package needs the SBML C library and static libraries for SBML for building R packages on Window is provided by `RTools4.0` [link](https://github.com/r-windows/rtools-packages)

I was able to successfully install `RTools4.0` and the additional SBML library. I checked that I have the header files for SBML in

`C:\rtools40\mingw64\include\sbml>` and the `libsbml.a` file n

`C:\rtools40\mingw64\lib>`

**Updated with latest information**

My package builds successfully on Mac OSX (Mojave) (without `RTools4.0`), however I am facing issues with installing my package on Windows.

The contents of my `Makevars.win` file are as follows:

```
CXX=clang++
PKG_CPPFLAGS= -I/mingw$(WIN)/include/
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) -lsbml -lbz2 -lz -lxml2 -liconv -lws2_32
```

I am able to select `rtools40` and build the package using the following commands from within `RStudio`

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/")  
devtools::install()
```

And the error I am getting is given below:

```
Installing Rcppsbml
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/sn248/Documents/GitHub/Rcppsbml"  \
  --library="C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'Rcppsbml' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw32/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c convertReactions.cpp -o convertReactions.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw32/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c printSBML.cpp -o printSBML.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw32/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello.cpp -o rcpp_hello.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Rcppsbml.dll tmp.def convertReactions.o printSBML.o rcpp_hello.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lsbml -lbz2 -lz -lxml2 -liconv -lws2_32 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcppsbml/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw64/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c convertReactions.cpp -o convertReactions.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw64/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c printSBML.cpp -o printSBML.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/mingw64/include/ -I"C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello.cpp -o rcpp_hello.o
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Rcppsbml.dll tmp.def convertReactions.o printSBML.o rcpp_hello.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lsbml -lbz2 -lz -lxml2 -liconv -lws2_32 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/Rlapack.dll: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcppsbml'
* removing 'C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcppsbml'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/sn248/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcppsbml'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I sort of understand why I am getting the error because even for `x64`, the 32-bit compiler `C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++` is being used. I don't know how to write the options to choose the correct compiler for `x64` since `BINPREF` only takes 1 directory as an input.

My `R.version` information is given below:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

The entire package code can be found at - https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbml

As seen from above, I am using `R-3.4.1` (which I can't update for now due to non-technical issues) and another version of Rtools (appropriate for `R-3.4.1`) also installed on my machine.

My questions are as follows:

Is there anyway to specify using `rtools40` while building the package using `RStudio`'s `Clean and Rebuild` option?

Even if I am able to install this library on my machine, will it work for `CRAN` checks?

Any help here would be very much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can post an answer to my problem that helped solved the installation problem.

I had to set `PATH` and `BINPREF` from within `R` as:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/rtools40/mingw$(WIN)/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/rtools40/mingw$(WIN)/bin/")
```

then installation using `devtools`

```
devtools::install()
```

This seems to install the package successfully on my Windows machine. However, I am not sure how do I make sure `RTools4.0` is selected for `CRAN`. Can I set these preferences in `Makevars.win`?

Comment: The follow up question in this answer will get more visibility if you ask it separately.

Comment: Rtools 4.0 is not official yet. You cannot use it for CRAN packages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess I will have to wait then.